# "JSON.stringifiy" returns URLEncoded data instead of JSON

Tags: jquery, html, json

I am writing an ASP.NET Web Forms app, and in one of the pages I have a modal form for registration that uses JQuery `.dialog()` to display it.  Because of the limitation in ASP.NET that a page can contain only one `form` element (the master page contains one, of course), the modal form I've created uses `DIV` tags.  So, the outer wrapper DIV is named "register".  Here's the DIV code:

```
        <div id="register" title="New Member Registration">
        <div class="modalCaption">
            <span class="red">Fields in red</span>
            <span>are required.  Your information is not shared with anyone and is fully encrypted in our
            database for your peace of mind.</span>
        </div>
        <br />
        <div class="row">
            <div class="row_label_red">Desired User Name :</div>
            <div class="row_field"><input type="text" name="userName" size="32" MaxLength="32" /></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="row_label_red">Your Email :</div>
            <div class="row_field"><input type="text" name="email" size="32" MaxLength="64" /></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="row_label_red">Password (6 char. min) :</div>
            <div class="row_field"><input type="password" name="pwd" size="32" MaxLength="32" /></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="row_label_red">Confirm Password :</div>
            <div class="row_field"><input type="password" name="conPwd" size="32" MaxLength="32" /></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="row_label">Your Last Name :</div>
            <div class="row_field"><input type="text" name="lastName" size="32" MaxLength="64" /></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="row_label">Your First Name :</div>
            <div class="row_field"><input type="text" name="firstName" size="32" MaxLength="64" /></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="row_label">ZIP/Postal Code :</div>
            <div class="row_field"><input type="text" name="zip" size="10" MaxLength="10" /></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="row_label">How Did You Hear About Us?</div>
            <div class="row_field">
                <select name="about">
                    <option Value="NONE" Selected>-- Please Choose One --</option>
                    <option value="News">News Article</option>
                    <option value="Google">Google Search</option>
                    <option value="Bing">Bing Search</option>
                    <option value="OtherSearch">Other Search Engine</option>
                    <option value="Friend">Friend's Referral</option>
                    <option value="Miscellaneous">Other</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div id="spStatus"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

To capture the form field data (since I'm having to use `DIV` instead of `form`), I am trying to use `JSON.stringify()` to format the data into JSON name/value pairs.  To test this, I am using the following:

```
var formData = JSON.stringify($.param($('#register').find(':input')));

var data = '{ "register": "' + formData + '"}"';
alert(data);
```

When I test this, I get this as the output of the `stringify()` call:

[image: Output of web page]

As you can see, the `stringify()` call is giving me URL-encoded data, which isn't what I need or really expected.  Can anyone offer some help here on what I'm missing?

Comment: `$.param` performs URL encoding.

Comment: So without having to write a bunch of manual code to extract the values from the input fields of the containing DIV, is there any OTHER way to convert the input fields into JSON?  How can I rewrite that line of code to achieve that?

Comment: Why do you need to convert it to JSON at all? Just use the URL-encoded result returned by `$.param()`.

Comment: Because I want to send the data to a web service using a POST.  The web service method expects an input parameter type of "Registrant", which is a custom data type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `$.param`, it serializes all the inputs into a URL-encoded string. Loop over the input elements and put them into an object, then convert that to JSON.

```
var formData = {};
$('#register').find(':input').each(function() {
    formData[this.name] = this.value;
});
var json = JSON.stringify(formData);
```

Comment: PERFECT!  That works!  I **REALLY** appreciate your help on this!

Comment: So now I get this error from the web service :  "Invalid object passed in, ':' or '}' expected. (20):"    -  What's THIS about??

Comment: Would need to see the code you're using to do the post. Also, I don't know ASP.NET, so I'm not really familiar with what it expects as input data.

Comment: Solved it.  I withdrew my "answer" with the code.  I was making mistakes in how I formatted the JSON being sent into the web service.  STUPID ME!!!!  Thanks again for your help on this.